# Sublime Linter with clang can't find header file in header

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm using sublime text with the sublime linter plugin especially with clang.

When I open a folder, it use the root of the folder as a header location, so if I have

```
src
├── World
│   ├── Chunk.cpp
│   ├── Chunk.hpp
│   ├── World.cpp
│   └── World.hpp
└── main.cpp
```

In World.cpp I need to include "World/World.hpp".

But if in World.hpp I include Chunk.hpp the same way ("World/Chunk.hpp"), I get an error but
in World.hpp I have no error. Error are only in file I include that include other file.

Comment: This seems more like a code issue than an issue with Sublime and SublimeLinter; however it's hard to tell because your question doesn't include any code for the files in question.

Comment: My code compile without any problem and is actually doing what's it's supposed to do.. It look's like it forget that there is a working compiling directory when looking in included file..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You need to tell clang where to look for the files, i.e. which directories you want to include. Go `Preferences` --> `Package Settings` --> `SublimeLinter` --> `Settings` and add a new section for `clang++`:

```
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
    "linters":
    {
        "clang++": {
            "I" : [
                "${folder}/src",
                "${file_path}",

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In your case the two include directories will actually point to the same path but in general, the first version is to include your source directory (e.g. you have a unit test from a different folder open which accesses code from you `src` directory) and the second line includes the location of your current file.

If you need different directories, find some more variables you can use [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html#variables).